# Работа с пикселями

Tags: c#

Подскажите пожалуйста, как на C# проверить по пикселям картинку с картинками в папке?

Comment: А что значит, проверить картинку с картинками?  Может сравнить?

Answer (score 1):

Если по пикселям, грузите свою картинку в Bitmap(System.Drawing):

```
    Bitmap picture = new Bitmap("путь до файла + имя файла");
```

Грузите вторую картинку с диска таким же способом. Тут нужно уточнить как вы будете проверять картинку. Можно например сначала проверить соответствие размеров:

```
    if (bitmap1.Width == bitmap2.Width && bitmap1.Height == bitmap2.Height)
```

Ну а дальше в циклах проверяем по пиксельно:

```
        bool isIdentity = true; //Предпологаем, что они одинаковые
        for (int y = 0; y < bitmap1.Height; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < bitmap1.Width; x++)
            {
                if (bitmap1.GetPixel(x, y) != bitmap2.GetPixel(x, y))
                {
                    isIdentity = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!isIdentity)
                break;
        }


        if (isIdentity)
            Console.WriteLine("Картинки одинаковы");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Картинки разные");
```

Ну стоит сказать что этот метод будет очень медленный. Для более быстрой проверки нужно использовать LickBits и BitmapData, например. И еще для получение файлов в папке:

```
        Directory.GetFiles(string path, string pattern)
```

Comment: LockBits всё же?